# Wordpress - Image upload custom field?

Tags: wordpress

Does anybody know if there is a way of having an image upload field on a post so I can upload a specific image for that post.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I used was the [Flutter](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/fresh-page/) module, which let me create custom content types.

Answer (score 1):

It's not currently possible (have been looking after it for months with no luck).

Are you trying to display that image as a thumbnail (while keeping it easy for the authors)?

The nicest approach is auto-detecting the first image in the post. Users don't need to deal with custom fields nor URLs:

```
// Get URL of first image in a post
function catch_that_image() {
    global $post, $posts;
    $first_img = '';
    ob_start();
    ob_end_clean();
    $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
    $first_img = $matches [1] [0];

    // no image found display default image instead
    if(empty($first_img)){
        $first_img = "/images/default.jpg";
    }
    return $first_img;
}

// With TimThumb
<img src="/thumb.php?src=<?php echo catch_that_image() ?>&w=200&zc=1&q=200" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"/>
```

Found it here: http://snipplr.com/view/23968/wordpress--get-first-image-of-post-without-custom-fields/

If that's not what you were looking for please give more details and we'll try to find a solution.

:)

Comment: In the end I used the Flutter module to create an image field. Works for me!

Answer (score 0):

It's not an ideal solution but I'm currently just using a custom field called "thumbnail" and putting the location of an uploaded image in there. Then, when I display the post details somewhere I use the value from the custom field as the `<img src="">` value.

To upload the image in the first place I just use the normal image upload tool in the editor and copy the uploaded name into the custom field as I'm writing the post.

Not very elegant but it works.